# Redux: where should I call mapDispatchProps?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a parent component (`ProfileScreen`). This component is composed of smaller child components like `ProfilePhoto`, `ProfileInfo`, etc. From the child components `ProfilePhoto` and `ProfileInfo` I can edit info about the user - theirs profile photo, their username, and so on. After I edit some of the user's data, I want to call `fetchUser` - this is a method from redux which fetches the current user from the database. That is, after I edit the user, I fetch it again from the database, so my components refresh and I can see the updated changes on the `ProfileScreen`. Currently, my structure is the following: inside `ProfileScreen` I call

```
const mapDispatchProps = (dispatch) =>
  bindActionCreators({ fetchUser }, dispatch)
```

and I pass `fetchUser` as a property to `ProfileScreen` and `ProfileInfo`. So that when the user finish the profile editing, I can call `fechUser` and the component reloads.

My question is - is this the correct way to do so? Is it not better to call

```
const mapDispatchProps = (dispatch) =>
      bindActionCreators({ fetchUser }, dispatch)
```

from the child components (`ProfilePhoto` and `ProfileInfo`) directly instead of passing it as property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is to see the specific situation. There is no right answer. But for your case, I recommend the former.

Make the `ProfileScreen` component a container component. It's stateful and impure. That means we use `mapDispatchProps` to inject the dispatch and the action creator into props. Handle the side effect in the container component such as DOM manipulation, network I/O, clean-up work.

Make the `ProfilePhoto` and `ProfileInfo` component presentational components. They are pure and stateless. That means they **should NOT** contain any side effect code. Just accept the props from the parent and render.

```
     ProfileScreen(container)
     /           \
ProfilePhoto  ProfileInfo
```

If the `ProfilePhoto` component gets more complex in the future, consider using it as a container component. The subcomponents of it are then used as the presentational component.

But keep in mind that more stateful and inpure components combined can lead to increased code complexity.

Further reading: [Presentational and Container Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)